# Screen protector for Elegoo Saturn?

Tags: maintenance, replacement-parts, lcd-screen

Can I cut down an iPad screen protector and stick it over the top of my Elegoo Saturn to protect the LCD from scratches or resin leaks\drips?

Or will this harm printing?

#### Additional information

A resin printer has an LCD screen underneath the resin tank. It shines a light up through the tank (which has a transparent bottom), which cures a thin layer of resin. The built plate then moves up slightly allowing more liquid resin to flow in underneath. The process then repeats.

There are particular wavelengths that must be allowed through. It's 405 nm (at least that's what is written on the side of the resin bottles that I use), which is UV light.

Answer (score 1):

The primary consideration you'd have by adding a screen protector is that you've added distance between the LCD panel and your build plate. Currently, the FEP film is in contact with the LCD panel. By inserting a screen protector, you've increased the distance light has to travel to reach the resin on the other side of the FEP film. It's certainly going to be a very small distance, but not a zero value.

The increased distance will allow a bit of diffraction and diffusion of the UV light passing through the protector film. If your models are not particularly detailed, you may not notice the difference.

Consider to print a [test model](http://ameralabs.com/blog/town-calibration-part/) designed for resin printers prior to installing the protector. Perhaps print more than one, in different resins. Once installed, print the same sequence again and examine carefully for detail changes.

Another aspect of this "project" is that screen protectors are removable.

[image: amerilabs test print]

Image courtesy of linked site. Note that the linked site requires the user to sign up for newsletters in order to receive the free STL file, but one can immediately unsubscribe. Other 3d resin printer test models may be available.

The site has useful information regarding "reading" the printed model with respect to the results.